# Split up serial data in delphi

Tags: delphi, serial-port, delphi-7, delimiter, arduino-uno

I am a newbie in Delphi programming and I need some help. I have a problem with spliting my serial data. This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer); 
var 
  DataByte : string;  
  x, i: integer;   
  save_data : TStringList;  
begin 
  save_data := TStringList.create;

  for x := 0 to Count-1 do begin
    ComPort1.ReadStr(DataByte,1);
    if DataByte = 'n' then
    begin
      memo1.Text := '';
    end
    else
    begin
      memo1.Text := memo1.Text + DataByte;
      Split(' ', DataByte, save_data);
    end; 
  end;   
  save_gyroX := save_data[0];   
  save_gyroY := save_data[1];   
  save_gyroZ := save_data[2];   
  save_accelX := save_data[3];   
  save_accelY := save_data[4];   
  save_accelZ := save_data[5];   
  SerialProcess();
  save_data.Free; 
end;
```

My `Split(' ', DataByte, save_data);` doesn't work. I don't understand because I just split `String` data which is taken from the serial port. This is my `Split()` procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.Split(const Delimiter: Char; Input: string; const Strings: TStrings) ; 
begin
  Assert(Assigned(Strings));
  Strings.Clear;
  Strings.Delimiter := Delimiter;
  Strings.DelimitedText := Input;
end;
```

I do not know why my program is giving me a `EStringListError` error.

Comment: Can you give an example of the Data you recive

Comment: Isn't `databyte` not just one character, which you cannot split? Why don't you split the complete string from `memo1.text`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ReadStr()` to read individual bytes, and calling `Split()`  on every byte (except for `'n'`).  So the `TStringList` will only ever hold 1 string at a time.  Like MBo said, you need to fix your loop to avoid that, eg:

```
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer); 
var 
  DataByte : string;  
  x: integer;   
  save_data : TStringList;  
begin 
  ComPort1.ReadStr(DataByte, Count);

  for x := 1 to Length(DataByte) do
  begin
    if DataByte[x] = 'n' then
    begin
      Memo1.Text := '';
    end
    else
    begin
      Memo1.Text := Memo1.Text + DataByte[x];
    end; 
  end;   

  save_data := TStringList.create;
  try
    Split(' ', DataByte, save_data);

    save_gyroX := save_data[0];   
    save_gyroY := save_data[1];   
    save_gyroZ := save_data[2];   
    save_accelX := save_data[3];   
    save_accelY := save_data[4];   
    save_accelZ := save_data[5];   
    SerialProcess();
  finally
    save_data.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

That being said, you are not taking into account that the number of bytes you receive for any given `OnRxChar` event call is *arbitrary*.  It is whatever *raw bytes* have been read at that exact moment.  You are assuming a full string with at least 6 delimited substrings, and that is simply not guaranteed.  You need to buffer the raw data as you receive it, and then parse and remove only completed strings from the buffer as needed.

Try something more like this:

```
var
  DataBuffer: string;

// consider using the OnRxBuf event instead...
procedure TForm1.ComPort1RxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer); 
var 
  DataByte : string;  
  x: integer;   
  save_data : TStringList;  
begin 
  ComPort1.ReadStr(DataByte, Count);
  DataBuffer := DataBuffer + DataByte;

  x := Pos('n', DataBuffer);
  if x = 0 then Exit;

  save_data := TStringList.Create;
  try
    repeat
      DataByte := Copy(DataBuffer, 1, x-1);
      Delete(DataBuffer, 1, x);

      Memo1.Text := DataByte;

      Split(' ', DataByte, save_data);
      if save_data.Count >= 6 then
      begin
        save_gyroX := save_data[0];   
        save_gyroY := save_data[1];   
        save_gyroZ := save_data[2];   
        save_accelX := save_data[3];   
        save_accelY := save_data[4];   
        save_accelZ := save_data[5];   
        SerialProcess();
      end;

      x := Pos('n', DataBuffer);
    until x = 0;
  finally
    save_data.Free; 
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

if Comport is Dejan Crnila CPort class, then this line

```
 ComPort1.ReadStr(DataByte,1);
```

replaces Databyte contents every time, and this string always is 1-byte length.

Just read all bytes from buffer with single call

```
ComPort1.ReadStr(DataByte, Count);
```

and do work with string